# Power - 1/2 Force x velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, work, power

A pump, taking water from a large reservoir, is used to spray a jet of water with speed 20m/s. The nozzle of the pipe has radius 0.05m, and is level with the surface of the reservoir (no change in PE).

Calculate the power of the pump.

So I calculated the power, using $P=Fv$ and $F=$$m/t$ $v$
My answer came out to be 62.8kW, which was double what they calculated (31.4kW) I'm wondering if needed to alter the formulae used which caused me to get it wrong?

Comment: You're not given a value for $t$, so how did you come to that?

Comment: @KyleKanos v=d/t, so distance in one second is 20 metres, so using Volume = Area x length i said Volume/time is the volume in one second, then found mass/time too

Comment: Note that $v\neq s/t$; that is an approximation that holds for certain cases (formally, $v_{avg}=\Delta s/\Delta t$ and $v_{inst}=ds/dt$). Assuming that $t=1$ is bad practice.

Comment: But time taken would be the same throughout the calculations. Force = mass x acceleration, using dimensional analysis Force = mass/time x velocity is the same thing. In 1 second, the water would travel 20 metres... in 0.5 seconds, it would travel 10, etc. So mass/time would remain the same, no matter the time chosen. In this case $V=$$d/t$ as the velocity is constant, there is no acceleration

Comment: No, $F\neq mv/t$; that is false and the true definition can be found in any introductory textbook. Note also that if acceleration is zero, then $F=0$ as well, since the **true** relation if $F=ma$. In this case, your power would be zero.

Comment: True definition of force being the rate of change of momentum? If acceleration is 0 it doesn't mean the force is 0, it means the resultant force is 0, and in this case we aren't looking at the resultant, we're looking at the retarding force? The answer below seems to show power certainly isnt 0.

Comment: I pointed out the falsehood of your previous comment's last sentence (you said, *In this case $V=d/t$ as the velocity is constant, there is no acceleration*) by pointing out that if $a=0$, then $F=ma=0$, which necessitates $P=Fv=0$. Obviously $P\neq0$, which means your assertion is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the kinetic energy of the water coming out in unit time. That is the power you need.

$$Power = \frac12 (\rho A v) v^2 = 31.4 kW$$

Comment: Beautiful, that works. Why doesn't the traditional formula work though? is it to do with the fact the water is being accelerated, so actually half the power is used?

Comment: Yes - if you look at the derivation of Bernoulli's equation you will see the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I'm not at uni and we don't study bernoulli till first year uni here in England (I'm in the year before uni) so I haven't looked at Bernoulli's equation in depth yet.

Comment: Don't apologize for what you don't know. Conservation of energy (which I'm sure you have learnt about) is a very powerful tool and works in this case. Bernoulli is really just conservation of energy applied to fluid flow.

Comment: Yeah, I started to really develop my interest in physics in january this year actually, so I'm learning some first year stuff out of a Schaum's outlines. Do you have any texts you'd recommend? I've also been trying to non rigorously learn Schrodingers equation and Einstein's field equations and some of the maths that goes along with it - youtube is a wonderful thing!

Comment: Without a doubt, if you are excited about physics and a little ahead of your A level peers (are they still called A levels in Britain?) you might love the first book of the Feynman Lectures on Physics. He has a wonderful way of making physics fun, approachable, and yet gives sufficiently rigorous treatment that you won't be "led astray". The entire body of lectures (pre youtube, sorry) is available for free online - http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/

Comment: Yes, they're still called A levels here haha, ah I had forgotten about Feynmanns lectures - I met them quite a while ago, but never really understood them - Now that I've developed my intuition and mathematical ability, I'll work my way through them.